# SQL specify order by of dynamic row values

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

The following SQl generates the table of results below:

```
select ks2en, 
    count(case result when 'C-' then 1 end) as 'C-',
    count(case result when 'C' then 1 end) as 'C',
   count(case result when 'C+' then 1 end) as 'C+',
   count(case result when 'B' then 1 end) as 'B',
   count(case result when 'A' then 1 end) as 'A'
from student join subject 
on subject.upn=student.upn 
where name='English'
group by ks2en;
```

What I would like to know is is it possible to specify the order of each row. Currently it reads as:

```
ks2en   C-  C   C+  B   A
        0   3   0   0   0
2a      0   0   0   0   0
3a      18  0   0   0   0
3b      0   0   0   0   0
3c      0   0   0   0   0
4a      3   11  1   1   0
4b      3   3   36  0   0
4c      1   26  0   0   0
5b      0   3   0   1   0
5c      3   12  4   33  0
```

I would like it to read as follows:

```
ks2en   C-  C   C+  B   A
        0   3   0   0   0
2a      0   0   0   0   0
3c      0   0   0   0   0
3b      0   0   0   0   0
3a      18  0   0   0   0
4c      1   26  0   0   0
4b      3   3   36  0   0
4a      3   11  1   1   0
5c      3   12  4   33  0
5b      0   3   0   1   0
```

One other note is that depending on the results the KS2en column may include other values with the following possible:

```
ks2en   

W
1c
1b
1a
2c
2b
2a      
3c      
3b      
3a      
4c      
4b      
4a      
5c      
5b      
5a
6c
6b
6a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hacky way (use whatever substring functions your db provides):

```
select 
    ks2en, 
    count(case result when 'C-' then 1 end) as 'C-',
    count(case result when 'C' then 1 end) as 'C',
    count(case result when 'C+' then 1 end) as 'C+',
    count(case result when 'B' then 1 end) as 'B',
    count(case result when 'A' then 1 end) as 'A'
from
    student 
        join 
    subject 
        on subject.upn = student.upn 
where 
    name='English'
group by 
    ks2en
order by
    case when ks2en = 'W' Then 0 Else 1 End,
    left(ks2en, 1),
    right(ks2en, 1) desc
```

The databasey way, create a table (or add a column to an existing table) with columns `ks2en, sequenceno`, say it's called ks2enSeq. Create a row for every value of ks2en, using ascending sequence numbers in the order you desire.

```
select 
    ks2en, 
    count(case result when 'C-' then 1 end) as 'C-',
    count(case result when 'C' then 1 end) as 'C',
    count(case result when 'C+' then 1 end) as 'C+',
    count(case result when 'B' then 1 end) as 'B',
    count(case result when 'A' then 1 end) as 'A'
from
    student 
        join 
    subject 
        on subject.upn = student.upn 
        inner join
    ks2enSeq k
        on k.ks2en = subject.ks2en
where 
    name='English'
group by 
    subject.ks2en
order by
    k.sequenceno
```

Comment: Awesome @Laurence thanks! One quick query. Is there any reason why the second method would be preferable? The hacky way seems quite elegant in itself. Are there security issues or performance issues I should consider?

Comment: The second method works, whatever the values of `ks2en`, the first depends on the specific values. If you had to add a new value later, adding data is usually easier then rewriting queries. There's no security issue with either method. At this scale, there's no performance difference either.

Comment: Thanks Laurence. Fortunately the values are educational performance measures that have been in place since I was at school, so unless something particularly dramatic happened government-wise here in the UK I should be ok to stick with the first method. Thanks again, both methods are great!